# "Next to the table were (laying) two old chairs and some books."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice

> Next to the table **were** two old chairs and some books.

or

> Next to the table **were laying** two old chairs and some books.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don’t quite mean the same thing, and old fogeys like me will say the second is not grammatical.

> Next to the table were lying two chairs

implies that the chairs were not upright. I literally startle when I read “lay” used when it is not meant and “lie” is.

> Next to the table were two chairs

says nothing except where the chairs are in relation to the table and, by absence, implies the chairs were in a normal position.